# How to connect Java Flight Recorder (from JDK 7 U 40) to a remote JBoss 7

Tags: ubuntu, monitoring, java, jboss, jmx

I have a remote Ubuntu server with Jboss 7 and a local Ubuntu desktop machine and I can already monitor JBoss using jconsole and visualvm scripts that come with it.

After the release of Java 7 Update 40, I wanted to try the Java Flight recorder in the same environment.

Googling around, it seams to be possible, but in my case after different combinations like the one bellow, I keep getting errors:

```
jmc  -J-Xbootclasspath/a:<paths to the multiple jboss remoting related jars copied from what jconsole script was using>
```

Results in:

```
Sep 23, 2013 2:35:05 PM com.jrockit.mc.rcp.application.ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor execute
WARNING: Unknown command 'J-Xbootclasspath/a:<all the given jars...>'. Error found at row 0, from position 0 to 732
```

Even trying with "jmc --launcher.appendVmargs -vmarg arguments" as briefly [explained in JMC's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jmc/intro.html), I have the same "Unknown command" warning, referencing vmarg in this case.

The Xbootclasspath is supported by Oracle's Java, As I can use it with no errors in:

```
java -Xbootclasspath/a:<any valid jar file> -version
```

A problematic parameter would print an error instead of the normal version output:

```
java -XDoesntExist -version
Unrecognized option: -XDoesntExist
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

So JMC's documentation might be inconsistent or incomplete. Any idea what is missing?